# security:authorize access="hasRole()" does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have security dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
<!-- SpringSecurity dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I'm also using

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

simply my issue is that I have to show two different menus for USER and ADMIN

```
<ul id="menu_top">
    <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <li><a href='<spring:url value="/admin/admin-stuff"/>'></a></li>

    </security:authorize>
    <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">          
        <li><a href='<spring:url value="/user/user-stuff"/>'></a></li>           
   </security:authorize>             
</ul>
```

this all the stuff does not work means when I login as `ADMIN` or `USER` nothing is shown, I've tried `hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')` as well but nothing works in this case.

Comment: can we see your spring security config? Did you enable expressions?

Comment: I am having the same problem, it is throwing me **403 access denied**, though I have the required authority. Any luck on solving this so far?

Comment: Well I solved mine. Just a thought, do look into the **intercept-url**'s to see if you do have access to those URLs.